# chapterbib is creating extra "References" entries in my table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies

In my table of contents, `\usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib}` is causing me to have for each section an:

**References**......page number

References......page number

**References**......page number

It is calling it 3 times (with 2 bold and one normal font)?  Any help or suggestions please? :)

Here is my code.

```
% preamble
\documentclass[phd,tocprelim]{cornell}
\let\ifpdf\relax
\usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib}
\usepackage{graphicx,pstricks}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{moreverb}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{hangcaption}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

%if you're having problems with overfull boxes, you may need to increase
%the tolerance to 9999
\tolerance=9999

\bibliographystyle{plain}

\renewcommand{\caption}[1]{\singlespacing\hangcaption{#1}\normalspacing}
\renewcommand{\topfraction}{0.85}
\renewcommand{\textfraction}{0.1}
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.75}

% document
\begin{document}

\contentspage
\tablelistpage
\figurelistpage

\include{Introduction}
\include{Growth}
\include{Particles}
\include{Conclusions}
\include{FutureWork}

\end{document}
```

At the end of each `.tex` file I included in my main file, I have the following code.

```
\pagebreak
% will print "REFERENCES" instead of "BIBLIOGRAPHY"
\renewcommand\bibname{{REFERENCES}}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
% adds "REFERENCES" to the table of contents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{REFERENCES}
\bibliography{IntroRef}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

Move `\renewcommand\bibname{{REFERENCES}}` to before `\begin{document}`

Have this at the end of each chapter file:

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
% adds "REFERENCES" to the table of contents
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{REFERENCES}
\bibliography{reference file}
```

Comment: This kind of worked for me.  Now I only have 2 repeats of references. I moved "\renewcommand\bibname{{REFERENCES}} " to before \begin{document} in the main document. I get 1 plain text references for each chapter but also 1 bold references right after.

Comment: I got it now.  It wasn't compiling. I did what you said and : \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{REFERENCES} it worked.  Thank you so much!